# How do I calculate a proper sample size to get a suitable power of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with an underlying Zipf distribution?

Tags: statistical-power, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, power-law, zipf

I have been trying to develop to calculate the sample size to maximize the power of KS test (±0.8) on an underlying Zipf distribution. I have tried estimating the power by performing simulations:

```
import random
nsim = 1000
pvals = []
for i in range(nsim):
    #x = random.uniform(1.0001,1.9999)
    x=1.1
    sample1 = np.random.zipf(x, 100)
    sample2 = np.random.zipf(x, 100)
    ksstat,pval = scipy.stats.kstest(sample1, sample2)
    pvals.append(pval)
```

Where I have both tried randomizing the Zipf parameter and setting it as a constant, but still have not found any significant distinctions;

```
alpha = 0.05
bool_pvals = []
for pval in pvals:
    if pval<alpha:
        bool_pvals.append(1)
    else:
        bool_pvals.append(0)

np.mean(bool_pvals)
```

And then calculated the rejection rate at alpha = 0.05, which occurs to be around ±0.04, which is terribly small.

Thus, I am looking for a way to improve the results I get, and there is a strong felling that can be missing something. Is there something I can change here? Or maybe there is a way to calculate the power of KS test analytically (even though it is a non-parametric test)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really proficient with Python, but your simulation seems correct. I would suggest at least $10^5$ iterations to get accuracy to a couple of decimal places for significance level or power. // The K-S test statistic is based on the largest discrepancy between the null CDF and the empirical CDF of the sample, so the statistic is not truly continuous. In R, 'ks.test' is not suitable for testing goodness of fit to discrete distributions. The p-value may be only approximate if there are ties in the data. The probability of rejection under the null hypothesis is not (quite) uniform.

Comment: The "usual" Kolmogorov--Smirnov test is not designed for discrete distributions.  I am aware that discrete versions of the test have been proposed (e.g., the one by Conover 1972).

Answer (score 1):

For an exact test with a uniform test statistic, the P-value of
the test under the null hypothesis is standard uniform. However,
the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, as implemented in R, meets neither
criterion. Here is the simulated distribution of the P-value of
a K-S test of fit to a *standard normal distribution,* under $H_0.$

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, ks.test(rnorm(100), pnorm)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04575
2*sd(pv <= .05)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0004178869
```

The true significance level the K-S test with $\alpha = 0.05$ is $0.0458 \pm 0.0004,$ which is
a little below 5%. Furthermore the P-value under $H_0$ is noticeably different
from standard uniform.

```
hdr = "Simulated Dist'n of K-S P-value Under Null"
hist(pv, prob=T, xlim=c(-.01,1.01), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="brown", n=1001)
```

[image]

For checking goodness of fit to appropriate distributions, you can
use simulation to find the actual significance level of a test with nominal 5% level, and you can find the power against specific alternative distributions, for particular sample sizes. However, even for goodness-of-fit to the continuous
standard normal distribution, results may not be what you expect. If your data can contain ties, then the K-S test statistic may not be accurate. So testing goodness-of-fit to any discrete distribution with the K-S test  is problematic.